# is_taxonomy() is not working

Tags: taxonomy

```
<?php
   if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

   get_header();

   $term = is_taxonomy('special-offers');
   if ($term) {
     echo "New template";
   }

   else{
?>
```

New template.

I want to set taxonomy by template. Any help?

Comment: Confirm, it's not a typo, like the taxonomy name is surely `special-offers`, not `special-offer`.

Answer (score 2):

use **is_tax()** instead of **is_taxonomy()** as is_taxonomy() depreciated since v3.0

Refer to http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax for usage reference